# Could stabilized aqueous ozone be bottled to prevent half life/sanitization window?

Tags: redox, aqueous-solution, reaction-control, ozone

Could stabilized aqueous ozone be bottled to prevent half life/sanitization window?

Typically upon creating stabilized aqueous ozone, it has a shelf life and a sanitization window of 24 hours from the time of production. Is this timeline due to oxidation, or would proper bottling prevent the degradation from occurring as fast? If not, is the process of it converting back to oxygen and water something that is inevitable due to time?